# Can I safely use a string_view if I need to eventually need to get a char pointer?

Tags: c++, c++20, cinterop

I'm working on some C++ code that also eventually needs to call OS-level C code, for example [scandir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html).

I'd like to use C++ for most of the codebase, which (to me) means that I'm mostly working with std::string instead of char pointers.

I have a method that accepts a string_view, so that I can pass in both std::string and char*, depending on whether the C++ or the "C interop" code needs to call it:

```cpp
std::optional<std::vector<FileInfo>> scan_directory(const std::string_view directory)
{
    if (directory.empty()) {
        return {};
    }

    struct dirent **namelist;
    int num = scandir(directory.data(), &namelist, nullptr, nullptr);
    [...]
}
```

Note the call to `data()` here, since scandir takes a `const char *`. Now, I saw [this note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data):

> Unlike std::basic_string::data() and string literals, data() may return a pointer to a buffer that is not null-terminated. Therefore it is typically a mistake to pass data() to a routine that takes just a const CharT* and expects a null-terminated string.

That got me thinking: Is there a better/safer way? I know that in practice, the callers will be null-terminated strings, but I don't want to create a hard-to-diagnose bug later on when I'm already aware there's a potential issue here. Though I guess that there's already no guarantee that a char* is null-terminated, so I'm not making the situation any worse.

Still, curious if there is a better option.

- Should I check the string_view for a null-terminator, and if none exists, create a `char[directory.size() + 1]{0}` and copy the characters myself?
- Or create two overloads, one that takes a std::string and one that takes a const char*?

I'm on `g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20201016 (Red Hat 10.2.1-6)` in C++20 mode via CMake's `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`.

Comment: The non-technical answer is that this isn’t what `string_view` is for: it allows you to accept a const char* or a (sub)string without copying, but if you need a `const char*` (for some underlying API), require one.

Comment: Any reason you are not using `std::filesystem`?

Answer (score 1):

When all you have is a `std::string_view`, you have no guarantees whatsoever that accessing beyond its `size()` is not undefined behavior. It's not an absolute guarantee that it's undefined behavior, but neither you have any guarantees that it's not. If the `string_view` was constructed using a pointer to a `\0`-terminated character string, but it's not included in the constructed `string_view`'s size, then you're arguably safe (I note that recent versions of libstdc++ have an option to do some boundary checking on vectors and string accesses, and if at some point in the future boundary checking get introduced for `string_view`s they'll trip you up, and you'll be out of luck). But it is certainly possible to construct a `string_view` with a pointer to a string that's not `\0` terminated, with an exact character count. In that case looking beyond its `size()` will result [in nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). And you have no way to determine whether this is the case.

The simplest solution for you here is to declare the parameter as `const char *`, and create an overload that takes a `const std::string &` alternative parameter, and then calls this function using `c_str`().

Comment: To be clear, indexing past the end of the `string_view` is definitely undefined behavior—but doing so via `data` depends only on the underlying array, and is thus “merely” error-prone.